# How to mask dynamic url in next js with getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

current url is: `http://localhost:3000/products/60e03e16229da058968f33c3`

but i want to mask it as `http://localhost:3000/products/product-1`

This is the getStaticPaths code that i have (uses apollo client to fetch the data)

```js
const GET_ALL_QUERY = gql`
  {
    products {
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = await client
    .query({
      query: GET_ALL_QUERY,
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const productsData = data.data.products;
      if (productsData.length) {
        return productsData.map((res) => {
          return { params: { id: res.id } };
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => Promise.reject(new Error(err)));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  try {
    const res = await client.query({
      query: GET_ONE_QUERY,
      variables: { id: params.id },
    });
    return {
      props: res.data.product,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

if i use

```js
<Link href={`/products/${product_id}` as={`/products/${product_name}`}>
</Link>
```

it doesnt seem to work. it is looking for `/product-1` page and returns page not found.

also in sever.js,
i have

```js
const server = express();

    server.get("/products/:id", (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = "/products";
      const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };
      console.dir("req.params.id = " + JSON.stringify(req.params.id));
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
    });
```

suspecting if this could be affecting the dynamic path.

I am not able to figure out the solution. Searched extensively but all resources refer to using only the id. Is this possible in nextjs ?

Comment: Try Specifying  the complete paths in getStaticPaths  `/products/${res.id}`) || [],

Comment: @DevAB you mean like return { params: { id: `/products/${res.id}` } } ? if so i am still getting 404 not found. also there is `getStaticProps` which depends on the `params.id`. i have added that code in the question now.

Comment: Replace return inside if 

return productsData.map((res) => {
          return { params: { id: res.id } };
        });

with

return productsData.map((res) => `/products/${res.id }`);

Then print Paths and check if you're getting the correct paths i.e 
products/1
products/2

Comment: Assuming your products names are unique, could you not generate the paths and query the API using the product name instead?

Comment: @DevAB doesnt seem to work. still getting 404 for `/products/apple` as the page is generated for `/products/1` only.

Comment: @juliomalves yeah ,can do that. but i just felt it is good practice to use id instead of name as with name we need to do some manipulation in url, query etc and we need to always be cautious to not have same name (eg scenario: same product - 2categories). pls let me know if my thought is correct